# My text does not change. I don't understand why

Tags: java, user-interface

I don't understand why this Java code isn't working. It's a GUI project I'm working on and I'm trying to get the JLabel to change to bold, italic, etc. via some check boxes:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class FontViewer {
static JCheckBox checkBoxBold;
static JCheckBox checkBoxItalic;
static JCheckBox checkBoxCenter;
static JPanel textPanel;
static JLabel textLabel;
static JComboBox fontName;
static JComboBox fontSize;

static ActionListener listener;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int FRAME_SIZE_X = 250;
    final int FRAME_SIZE_Y = 400;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(FRAME_SIZE_X, FRAME_SIZE_Y);

    JPanel face = new JPanel();
    face.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    JPanel bottomFace = new JPanel();
    bottomFace.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    textPanel = createTextPanel();

    JPanel checkBoxPanel = createCheckBoxPanel();

    JPanel comboPanel = createComboPanel();

    JPanel radioButtonsPanel = createButtonsPanel();

    face.add(textPanel);

    bottomFace.add(checkBoxPanel);
    bottomFace.add(comboPanel);
    bottomFace.add(radioButtonsPanel);

    face.add(bottomFace);

    frame.add(face);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    class FontListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            int fontStyle = 0;
            if (checkBoxBold.isSelected())
                fontStyle = fontStyle + Font.BOLD;
            if (checkBoxItalic.isSelected())
                fontStyle = fontStyle + Font.ITALIC;
            if (checkBoxCenter.isSelected())
                textPanel.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            String textFont = (String) fontName.getSelectedItem();

            int textSize = Integer.parseInt((String) fontSize
                    .getSelectedItem());

            textLabel.setFont(new Font(textFont, fontStyle, textSize));
            textLabel.repaint();
        }
    }

    listener = new FontListener();
}

private static JPanel createTextPanel() {
    textPanel = new JPanel();

    textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    textLabel = new JLabel("Java Text");
    textPanel.add(textLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    return textPanel;
}

private static JPanel createCheckBoxPanel() {
    JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();

    checkBoxBold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
    checkBoxItalic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
    checkBoxCenter = new JCheckBox("Center");

    checkBoxBold.addActionListener(listener);
    checkBoxItalic.addActionListener(listener);
    checkBoxCenter.addActionListener(listener);

    checkBoxPanel.add(checkBoxBold);
    checkBoxPanel.add(checkBoxItalic);
    checkBoxPanel.add(checkBoxCenter);

    return checkBoxPanel;
}

private static JPanel createComboPanel() {
    JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();

    fontName = new JComboBox();
    fontName.addItem("Serif");
    fontName.addItem("Courier");

    fontSize = new JComboBox();
    fontSize.addItem("12");
    fontSize.addItem("24");
    fontSize.addItem("36");

    comboPanel.add(fontName);
    comboPanel.add(fontSize);

    return comboPanel;
}

private static JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
    JPanel radioButtonsPanel = new JPanel();

    JRadioButton redButton = new JRadioButton("Red");
    JRadioButton whiteButton = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");

    ButtonGroup colors = new ButtonGroup();
    colors.add(redButton);
    colors.add(whiteButton);
    colors.add(blueButton);

    radioButtonsPanel.add(redButton);
    radioButtonsPanel.add(whiteButton);
    radioButtonsPanel.add(blueButton);

    return radioButtonsPanel;
}
```

}

When I press any of the check boxes, the JLabel object does not change. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you so much in advance.

Note: As of now, I only wish to know why the check boxes are not working. This code is incomplete, I'm aware of this. Thank you once again.

Comment: are you sure all the code is relevant?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over Flow. Please try to find the minimal relevant subset of your code. It is very hard to understand even what your problem is from 100 code lines.

Comment: does this even compile? `class FontListener implements ActionListener {` is inside the `main` method.

Comment: @jlordo There's nothing wrong with an inner class declaration.  It can appear anywhere a regular declaration can.

Answer (score 4):

At the time you added the listener to the check boxes, the value of `listener` was `null`.  `listener` is not initialized until the very end of the main method.

Comment: You guys are lifesavers! Thank you so much for all your help! And I'm sorry for the long code: I'm new to this site and was thinking some of you might have wanted to try the code out yourselves to see what the issue was! Again, THANK YOU!

Comment: @user1800967 In fact for me the code was just enough and it was definitely runnable, so heads up!

Comment: This is one of those cases where having the entire code allowed a definitive answer without back-and-forth comments.  However, it is not generally a good idea to post hundreds of lines of code if the problem can be reduced to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I understand. I will condense code in the future as much as possible for the sake of clarity. Again, thank you so much Jim!

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the listeners before creating `JFrame`. It worked for me. Of course the definition of the `FontListener` class has to be put before `listener` declaration accordingly.

```
//...
listener = new FontListener();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//...
```